# mongoose and express not reading from .env file

Tags: express, mongoose, environment-variables, dotenv

I am having some trouble importing a .env file into my project. I have fallbacks in place so I didn't notice the issue until I was almost done with my project and was having trouble implementing a paypal button that wouldn't load. Now I am testing and I realize that all my env files have not been importing :/

I am new to using express but I think I did everything correctly as far as I can tell (but obviously not lol). I have imported all my dependencies and I am using dotenv:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
```

My code for importing my paypal .env file:

```
app.get("/api/config/paypal", (req, res) => {
```

res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || "sb");
});

my .env file (located at the root of my folder structure)

```
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID= my key info here without quotes
```

Where the code is eventually being called

```
const addPayPalScript = async () => {
  }, [dispatch, orderId]);        const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${data}`;
      script.async = true;
```

I am not sure why this configuration is not working. I have tried to move the env file to the same folder as the file that is calling it but this just fails to compile with an error. (I have a frontend and a backend folder) I have tried to move the env file to the root of the backend folder and it fails to compile with the same error message. It seems like the root of the project file is the correct location for the env file and all the information I can find online seems like my code is okay, but I still can not load the link for the paypal button when it is clicked on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do :

Instead of `import dotenv from "dotenv";`

Use :

`import {config} from "dotenv";`
`config()`

The only function you need from the `dotenv library` to read your `.env` configuration is `config`, to invoke it i've done `config()`

Now you can access values by doing : `process.env.YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I imported dotenv instead of config but I forgot to mention that I did call the config with dotenv.config(); Maybe this has to do with Paypal it's self. I am starting to think the error is with the routing from Paypal's end.